# JUnit - Use method in test from another class

Tags: java, selenium, methods, junit, automation

The scenario is the following:

I have a class that executes tests for a section of a project.

```
public class section1 extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        //somecode
    }
}
```

The thing is that in test1, I want to use a Method that's defined in another test class (we're not using Page Objects in the automation project).

```
public class section2 extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        //somecode
        methodOne();
    }

    void methodOne(){
        //somecode
    }
}
```

So, I've tried creating an instance and access to the method through it

```
section2 sec2 = new section2();
.
.
.
@Test
    public void test1() {
        //somecode
        section2.methodOne();
    }
```

But it throws a NullPointerException as soon as it starts executing the method.

Then, I tried just extending the class section1 to section2 and use the method, so here it executes the method but, as soon as test1 finishes, it starts executing the tests from the extended class, in this case, test2.

How can I do to prevent that, or is there another way to use the method without extending and not making the method public?

Comment: Move methodOne() to BaseTest - why not?

Comment: Can you mention on which line you are getting the NullPointerException

Comment: @BorLaze because it's not only methodOne, it's like three methods, and they're for filling checkout info... you can imagine those are long

Comment: @SameerArora I'm getting it at the line on Section1 class inside the test1, on the line where it executes the method. It doesn't give me more info about what it's failing inside that method

Answer (score 0):

```
Section 1 extends BaseTest

Section 2 extends BaseTest
```

Why don't you try this :

```
Section 2 extends Section 1
```

Comment: I'm sorry, actually I wrote it wrong, but in the code I tried: Section1 extends Section2 / Section2 extends BaseTest

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in the section1 class:

```
section2 sec2;
@Before
public void initialize() {
    sec2 = new section2();
}
```

As we are using the @Before JUnit annotation above, this 'initialize()' method will get executed first there by initializing the 'section2' class.

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    sec2.methodOne();
}
```

Then in the @Test JUnit method will get executed so you won't get NPE.

Comment: Added it but still gives me the NullPointerException

Comment: Can you share the error message? I mean the full stack trace?